# AWS-PHP-SDK S3 Bucket Creation Exception Not throwing on Duplicate Bucket name

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, exception, sdk

I have already created a bucket in Amazon S3 with the following code from my local WAMP server. When I run the same code to check for **BucketAlreadyExistsException** for the same bucket name it is not giving the desired exception message.

---

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Aws\S3\S3Client;
use Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception;
use Aws\S3\Exception\BucketAlreadyExistsException;

$bucketName = 'user_phptestbucket354';

$client = S3Client::factory(array(
    'profile' => 'userprofile',
    'credentials' => array(
                'key'    => 'ABC ------- P',
                'secret' => 'ZYX ------------------------- A')
));

try{
    $result = $client->createBucket(array(
                    'Bucket' => $bucketName ));
}catch(BucketAlreadyExistsException $err){

    // Get Error Code
    echo 'Err Code: ' . $err->getAwsErrorCode();
    echo '<br />';

    // Get Error Message
    echo 'Err Msg: ' . $err->getMessage();
    echo '<br />';
}
```

Comment: Okay... what does it do, if not what you expect?

Comment: I expect that this will throw **BucketAlreadyExistsException**. Testing the AWS PHP SDK for first time. Although I am already using **doesBucketExist like this** -                                              if(!($client->doesBucketExist($bucketName)))
            {
             $client->createBucket(array(
    'Bucket' => $bucketName
   ));
            }

Comment: anybody wish to provide explanation ??